# Generic TEXT/CLOB data type for cross-database SQLAlchemy application

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am working on Python web application that uses MySQL as a database backend on the development environment and Oracle 11g on the production environment. Is there a specific way to unify the SQLAlchemy text fields, so that they work both on MySQL and Oracle database? For the Oracle backend in the models I use `sqlalchemy.CLOB` and for MySQL `sqlalchemy.TEXT`.

Comment: Are you creating a database from the SA model? Also on production?

Comment: Yes, the database is created from the SA model.

Comment: @van I bet you are able to answer this question. Am I right? :)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: i have an idea, will try to find time later tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @agronholm on #sqlalchemy one is supposed to use generic SQLAlchemy type [`Text`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) (which `TEXT` is specialization of):

> A variably sized string type.
>
> In SQL, usually corresponds to CLOB or TEXT. Can also take Python
>   unicode objects and encode to the database’s encoding in bind params
>   (and the reverse for result sets.) In general, TEXT objects do not
>   have a length; while some databases will accept a length argument
>   here, it will be rejected by others.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using this official documentation trick should do the trick: [Overiding Type Compilation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/custom_types.html#overriding-type-compilation). In this case i would keep `CLOB` as original because it is used in production, and would apply a compilation for `mysql`:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.types import CLOB

@compiles(CLOB, "mysql")
def compile_binary_mysql(type_, compiler, **kw):
    return "TEXT"
    # @note: this will handle other parameter such as `length`
    # return compiler.visit_TEXT(type_, **kw)
```

*Note that it is strongly advised to use the same RDBMS for production/test/development to avoid these and other issues.*

Comment: Isn't using generic SQLAlchemy type `Text` the preferred solution here? It's automatically translated to `CLOB` for Oracle and `TEXT` for MySQL.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: You are right, I think it will work. The preferred solution though would be to use the same database engine :)

Comment: Is it safe to visit one concrete type (`TEXT`) as part of compilation of other concrete type (`CLOB`)? Any two concrete types can have different semantics which would make them incompatible.

Comment: Good question, but I would consider them compatible. Why I also think it is a "good" solution (the "best" is just use the same database engine) is that the `CLOB` is the datatype used in production, while the other is for dev/test only.  Give you other examples: `mssql`'s `BIT` datatype does not really have equivalent in `sqlite`. I think it is safe to compile it as one sees fit. Or another example would be UUID (GUID).