# Unlimited width text (Unicode) column with SQLAlchemy + Oracle 11g

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, unicode, sqlalchemy

I'm porting SQA-managed database from PostgreSQL to Oracle.

In PostgreSQL all I had to do to have column width unlimited for practical purposes  was declaring field as `Unicode` that SQA translated to PostgreSQL' `varchar` (max column width 2147483647 bytes apparently).

However, when working on Oracle backend SQA's `Unicode` field generates `NVARCHAR2` column with maximum width of 4000 (even if I declared it that way, I'm not sure if it's efficient).

I have some values in (unindexed) columns that exceed the width that Postgres can index with default index, but it still can handle them.

Is there some specific type in Oracle dialect for SQA that I can use for getting large column width *and* I could still query them in typical ways in SQA and SQA Core (lower level SQL Expression language)?

Would `CLOB` or `NCLOB` datatype work for large column width, indexing the normal way and querying in SQA/SQA Core?

Comment: Will `CLOB` or `NCLOB` datatype not work?

Comment: Is this a duplicate: [Generic TEXT/CLOB data type for cross-database SQLAlchemy application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378389/generic-text-clob-data-type-for-cross-database-sqlalchemy-application)

Comment: @MT0: that's a very good question, which is why I added it to my question.

Comment: @MT0: not really, as I'm not sure about querying `CLOB` fields in Oracle working the same way as e.g. `NVARCHAR2` that SQA generates, while the question you linked to was limited to equivalent of TEXT from MySQL.